# Почему ThreadPoolExecutor работает на MacOS, но перестает работать на Linux

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Я столкнулся с проблемой

Я распараллелил процессы с помощью `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Вот пример:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(self.process_by_label, self.metrics)
```

Весь код не навожу, чтобы не путать никого

Метод `self.process_by_label` вычитывает данные с одного файла и на основании `self.metrics` записывает в множество других файлов. Исходный файл (с которого мы вычитываем данные) для всех процессов одинаковый.`self.metrics` - это по сути список на основании которого мы меняем контент и создаем множество новых файлов.

Исходный файл очень большой (124 GB). Его я вычитываю построчно, по этому проблем с оперативной памятью у меня нет.

Когда я этот скрипт запускаю локально на `MACOS` - у меня процессы распараллеливаются и все работает так как я ожидаю. Когда я переношу скрипт в клауд, где все работает на `linux` - процесс просто зависает.

Когда я запускаю все в одном процессе на `MACOS` и на `linux` - так же все работает

Вопрос: почему на `linux` логика может не работать?
Может ли это быть связано с тем, что все процессы читают с одного файла?
Или может это связано с какими то различиями реализации мультипроцессинга для `linux` и `MACOS`?

Буду благодарен за любые советы в этом направлении...

Спасибо

Comment: Вот нашел небольшую заметку про разницу в паралельности между linux и windows, но может поможет. https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/differences-between-multiprocessing-windows-and-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Из map надо бы вычитывать результат. Возможно gc на линуксе кушает фьючерсы раньше чем они запустились. Ведь их никто не ждет.

Модуль concurrent я бы рекомендовал использовать через asyncio, а не напрямую.

Ну а если нельзя запускать луп, то тредовый мап есть в multiprocessing.dummy.Pool().map()